# How to make a validation for existing user in database in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I created a form and and some validation but it's not enough for me

```
<form action="insc.php" method="post" name="inregistrarec">
      <div class="reg_section personal_info">
      <h3>Informatii generale despre companie</h3>
     <input name="Denumirea" type="text"  placeholder="Denumirea" style="width:440px;" >     
     <input name="Domeniul"  type="text"  placeholder="Domeniul" style="width:440px;">
     <input name="Adresa"    type="text"  placeholder="Adresa" style="width:440px;">
     <input name="Tel"       type="text"  placeholder="Telefonul" style="width:440px;">
     <input name="Email"     type="text"  placeholder="E-mail" style="width:440px;">
     <input name="Fax"       type="text"  placeholder="Fax" style="width:440px;">
     <input name="file"      type="file"  placeholder="Foto" style="width:440px;">
    </div>
      <div class="reg_section password">
     <input name="Login"     type="text"     placeholder="Login" style="width:440px;">   
     <input name="password"  type="password" placeholder="Parola" style="width:440px;">
     <input name="password1" type="password" placeholder="Confirma parola"style="width:440px;">

     </div>
      <div class="reg_section password">
      <h3>Despre companie</h3> 
      <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"        placeholder="Descriere" style="width:440px;"></textarea>
      <input    name="url"      type="url"  id="url" placeholder="Pagina companiei" style="width:440px;">
        </div>
     </p>
      <p class="submit">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Înregistrare"></p>
      </form>




   <script type='text/javascript'>
    var inregistrarecValidator = new Validator("inregistrarec",{enable_smart_live_validation:false, message_style:'messagebox'});
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Denumirea",{required:true,message:"Completati cimpul \"Denumirea\""} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Domeniul",{required:true,message:"Completati cimpul \"Domeniul\""} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Domeniul",{alpha:true,message:"Completati cimpul doar cu caractere"} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Adresa",{required:true,message:"Completati cimpul \"Adresa\""} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Tel",{required:true,message:"Completati cimpul \"Telefon\"!"} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Tel",{numeric:true,message:"Telefonul trebuie sa fie format din cifre"} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Email",{required:true,message:"Introduceti Emailul"} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Email",{email:true,message:"Introduceti un Email valid"} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Fax",{numeric:true,message:"The input for Fax should be a valid numeric value"} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("file",{req_file:true,message:"File upload is required for file"} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Login",{required:true,message:"Completati Cimpul \"Login\""} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Login",{minlen:"6",message:"Login-ul trebuie sa fie compus din minim 6 caractere"} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Login",{maxlen:"20",message:"Login-ul trebuie sa fie compus din maxim 20 caractere"} );
     inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("password",{required:true,message:"Please fill in password"} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("password1",{required:true,message:"Please fill in password1"} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("password",{minlen:"6",message:"Parola trebuie sa fie compusa din minim 6 caractere"} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("password1",{maxlen:"20",message:"Parola trebuie sa fie compusa din maxim 20 caractere"} );
    inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("password",{eqelmnt:"password1",message:"Parolele nu coincid"} );

    </script>
```

Here I make a validation for my site  and I need to verify if this user exist in database. What function can I add to obtain what I need.
I found one function like :
`inregistrarecValidator.addValidation("Login",{remote:"?sfm_check_unique=y",message:"Acest login exista"} )`;
But I don't know how this work and how to make connection with database. I insert data in database with `php` and this is the code:

```
<?php
    $denumirea = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Denumirea']);
    $domeniul = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Domeniul']);
    $adresa = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Adresa']);
    $tel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Tel']);
    $email =mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['Email']);
    $fax = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Fax']);
    $file = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['file']);
    $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Login']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password1']);
    $descriere= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textarea']);
    $url= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url']);



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $id = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("site", $id);
    $dom=mysql_query("insert into domeniu (Domeniu) values ('$domeniul')")  or die(mysql_error());
    $id_dom=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `domeniu` order by Id_Domeniu desc limit 1;")  or die(mysql_error()); 

    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($id_dom);

    if($numrows!=0)
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($id_dom))
        {
            $domeniu_id=$row['Id_Domeniu'];
            $domeniu=$row['Domeniu'];

            }
    }
    $res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO companie (Den_Comp,Id_Domeniu_FK,Adresa,Tel,Email,Fax,Foto,Login,Parola,Descriere,Pag_Comp) VALUES ('$denumirea','$domeniu_id', '$adresa','$tel','$email','$fax','$file','$login','$password','$descriere','$url')") or die(mysql_error("eroare"));
header('location:index(2).php');
}
else echo"eroare";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax functionality to check for existing user. You can use Javascript or more easliy using any of the Javascript libraries like jQuery. Assuming that you have created a file named check_username.php for checking the username.

Javascrip example:

```
function sendAjax(url) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              alert(xmlhttp.responseText);//Your Ajax response will be alertted here. Do What ever you want with the result
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", 'check_username.php', true); // Ajax request send here to check_username.php
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

In JQuery

```
$.ajax({
  url: "check_username.php",
}).done(function(response) {
  alert(response);//Response alerted here
});
```